# Current number page and document's number page

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdf-generation, itext

I'm trying to make a PDF document with iTextSharp.

I don't know how to make a header with "currentPageNumber/documentsNumberOfPages" like that :

[image: sample]

**Follow-up question**

For the moment, based on the original answers, I have this :

```
public class StockComp : iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfPageEventHelper
{
    PdfTemplate templateNumPage;

    public string Header
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        templateNumPage = writer.DirectContent.CreateTemplate(30, 250);
    }

    public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
        try
        {
            table.SetWidths(new int[] { 10, 10, 2 });
            table.TotalWidth = 800;
            table.LockedWidth = true;
            table.DefaultCell.FixedHeight = 20;
            table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
            table.AddCell(Header);
            table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
            table.AddCell(string.Format("Page {0} of", writer.PageNumber));
            PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(Image.GetInstance(templateNumPage));
            cell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
            table.AddCell(cell);
            table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 34, 803, writer.DirectContent);
        }
        catch (DocumentException de)
        {
            throw de;
        }
    }

    public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
    {
        ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(templateNumPage, Element.ALIGN_LEFT, new Phrase((writer.PageNumber - 1).ToString()), 2, 2, 0);
    }
}
```

But, I don't understant why, it's just show the "templateNumPage" and doesn't show the first and second cells which contains "Header" and "Page {0} of"...

I declare my document like this :

```
// On récupère le n ombre de lignes et de colonne de la GridView
        int noOfColumns = gvReportingStockComp.Columns.Count;
        int noOfRows = gvReportingStockComp.Rows.Count;

        // On fixe les informations concernant les tailles de police du document PDF
        float HeaderTextSize = 8;
        float ReportNameSize = 10;
        float ReportTextSize = 8;
        float ApplicationNameSize = 7;

        // --- On crée le document final --- \\
        Document document = null;
        // Le document final sera-t-il en mode paysage ou non
        bool LandScape = true;
        if (LandScape == true)
        {
            // Comme le document est en mode paysage, on execute une rotation sur ces dimensions
            // Les 4 derniers paramètres de la fonction correspondent aux marges du document sur les bords
            document = new Document(PageSize.A4.Rotate(), -50, -50, 50, 30);
        }
        else
        {
            // On spécifie les dimensions du document
            // Les 4 derniers paramètres de la fonction correspondent aux marges du document sur les bords
            document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 0, 0, 0, 0);
        }

        // --- On instancie le Writer et la classe d'evenement associée --- \\
        // Le flux de sortie
        PdfWriter pdfW = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, Response.OutputStream);
        // La classe évenement associée
        StockComp evenement = new StockComp();
        pdfW.PageEvent = evenement;

        // --- Ouverture du document --- \\
        document.Open();

        // --- On ajoute les valeurs dans le document --- \\

        // On créer un PdfTable qui contient le même nombre de colonne que la GridView
        // On ajoute 3 car l'on souahite que la cellule composant ait une taille de 4
        // et le autre cellule une taille de 1.
        PdfPTable mainTable = new PdfPTable(noOfColumns+3); 

        // Notre document sera composé de au minimum 4 lignes :
        // 1 : Nom appli + Date
        // 2 : Titre du tableau
        // 3 : Saut de ligne
        // 4 : Headers du tableau
        // X : Lignes du tableau
        mainTable.HeaderRows = 4;

        evenement.Header = "Trèves";

        // On génère les noms de colonnes et on les insèrent
        for (int i = 0; i < noOfColumns; i++)
        {
            PdfPCell cell = null;

            Phrase ph = null;

            ph = new Phrase(gvReportingStockComp.Columns[i].HeaderText, FontFactory.GetFont("Tahoma", HeaderTextSize, iTextSharp.text.Font.BOLD));

            cell = new PdfPCell(ph);

            cell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER;

            if (i == 1)
            {
                cell.Colspan = 4;
            }

            mainTable.AddCell(cell);
        }

document.Add(mainTable);

//pdfW.PageNumber*/
document.Close();
```

Please, help me. Thanks ;)

Comment: http://bit.ly/18aEkqL

Comment: possible duplicate of [Page X of Y issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845367/page-x-of-y-issue)

Comment: Smartis, it's not funny...
Thanks Bruno, i will read it.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with the page header thing (also my computer's not showing the image for some reason...) but to get the page number in iTextSharp you can do:

```
iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader pdfReader = new iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfReader(documentImage);
// may want to check if pdfReader is null before doing below
int numPages = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
```

Where `documentImage` is of type `byte[]`, but you could use any of `PdfReader`'s overloads.

Answer (score 0):

The [iText in Action — 2nd Edition](http://itextpdf.com/book/) example [MovieCountries1.java](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=104) / [MovieCountries1.cs](http://kuujinbo.info/iTextInAction2Ed/index.aspx?ch=Chapter05&ex=MovieCountries1) illustrates how to create a document with *Page X/Y* information.

The central construction brick is a `PdfPageEventHelper` adding header information:

```
/**
 * Inner class to add a table as header.
 */
protected class TableHeader : PdfPageEventHelper {
  /** The template with the total number of pages. */
  PdfTemplate total;

  /** The header text. */
  public string Header { get; set; }

  /**
   * Creates the PdfTemplate that will hold the total number of pages.
   */
  public override void OnOpenDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    total = writer.DirectContent.CreateTemplate(30, 16);
  }

  /**
   * Adds a header to every page
   */
  public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(3);
    try {
      table.SetWidths(new int[]{24, 24, 2});
      table.TotalWidth = 527;
      table.LockedWidth = true;
      table.DefaultCell.FixedHeight = 20;
      table.DefaultCell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
      table.AddCell(Header);
      table.DefaultCell.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;
      table.AddCell(string.Format("Page {0} of", writer.PageNumber));
      PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell(Image.GetInstance(total));
      cell.Border = Rectangle.BOTTOM_BORDER;
      table.AddCell(cell);
      table.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 34, 803, writer.DirectContent);
    }
    catch(DocumentException de) {
      // ...
      throw de;
    }
  }

  /**
   * Fills out the total number of pages before the document is closed.
   */
  public override void OnCloseDocument(PdfWriter writer, Document document) {
    ColumnText.ShowTextAligned(
      total, Element.ALIGN_LEFT,
// NewPage() already called when closing the document; subtract 1
      new Phrase((writer.PageNumber - 1).ToString()),
      2, 2, 0
    );
  }
}
```

It is employed like this:

```
// step 1
using (Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 54, 36)) {
  // step 2
  PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
  TableHeader tevent = new TableHeader();
  writer.PageEvent = tevent;
  // step 3
  document.Open();
  [...]
}
```

**Beware:** The table written by the `OnEndPage` code above is formatted for a portrait A4 document. If you use a landscape document size, you have to adjust some of the values, namely the `TotalWidth` value `527` and the writing coordinates `34, 803` of `table.WriteSelectedRows` as otherwise your header may be partially off-page.

There is also an alternative. Cf. [Keyword: Page numbers > page X of Y](http://itextpdf.com/themes/keyword.php?id=223).

Comment: Thanks, I have edit my post because I have an other question :/

Comment: Editing a question like that is very bad style. Now none of the comments and answers seem to fit anymore. Whenever you have other questions, create a new question. Or at least, if the questions are connected, leave the original question text and add the other question titled as e.g. "follow-up question" underneath.

Comment: Concerning your problems, though, I added a warning in my answer concerning the table width and position hard-coded into the sample; if you are using a different document format, you have to adjust those hard-coded values, too. Your code currently uses A4 landscape. Thus, the cells you are missing quite likely are located above the page border. Furthermore you use negative margins. I doubt you'll be happy with them in the long run.

Comment: Furthermore you seem add only cells for two columns. The table has three! The third one for width cosmetics, I assume.

Comment: Thanks, I will trying it. And sorry for my post edition, I don't understand correctly the rules for this forum ;)